# Generating an object file ( .o ) for a linker

Tags: c, linker, ld, object-files

I want to create a c program that creates .o files for the linker on my computer (ld). Gcc does this when I do the command `gcc -c myfile.c`. Are there any resources that show how to make an object file for a linker?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own compiler?

Comment: I don't know whether this is a useful suggestion for what you're doing, but the easiest way is to generate a `.c` file and run `gcc` on it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: @Barmar this doesn't run on osx

Comment: @user3689979, are you familiar with the __Elf__ file format?  You might want to start with a program to dump the content of an Elf file, then you will surely be more prepared to build an Elf file using C.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer I dont want to build an elf file. I want to build the file that is made when `gcc -c myfile.c` is done. That creates and object file which is linked by ld later

Comment: @user3689979, of course.  Now I understand.  Do you know the format of the file generated by __gcc -c__?

Comment: ELF is used for both object and executable files, as mentioned in the beginning of the Wikipedia article I linked to. OS X uses Mach-O format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a file similar to a file produced by `gcc -c`, it is important to first understand the format of the file produced.

First, create a file with gcc, and then see if it's format can be reverse-engineered.  I will use the following C program (hello.c) to perform this task:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
   {
   printf("Hello world\n");
   return(0);
   }
```

Now, compile the file without linking it:

```
gcc -Wall -c -o hello.o hello.c
```

The above code will create `hello.o` from `hello.c`.  This file is compiled, but not yet linked.

Many files today contain bytes in the header of the file that help identify its format.  These identifying bytes are termed 'file magic'.  Google 'file magic' and you can find details on how to identify may types of files.

To identify this file type, look for a magic number in the first few lines of a hexdump of the file:

```
> hexdump -Cn 64 hello.o
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  50 04 40 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.....P.@.....|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 1a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@...............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  09 00 40 00 2a 00 27 00  |....@.8...@.*.'.|
00000040
```

The identity of the file's format is revealed, in this case, by the first few bytes of the file; 45 4c 46 = `ELF`.  Hence, the output  of `gcc -c` is a file in the `ElF` format.

Hence, in order to create similar output from a C program, an understanding of the ELF file format is required.

Many *nix systems include a program called `readelf` that will translate the contents of an ELF file.  For example:

```
> readelf -a hello.o
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400450
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6680 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         42
  Section header string table index: 39

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.SuSE        NOTE             0000000000400274  00000274
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             000000000040028c  0000028c
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 5] .hash             HASH             00000000004002b0  000002b0
       0000000000000024  0000000000000004   A       7     0     8
  [ 6] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         00000000004002d8  000002d8
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       7     0     8
  [ 7] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000004002f8  000002f8
       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   A       8     1     8
  [ 8] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000400358  00000358
       000000000000003d  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 9] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000400396  00000396
       0000000000000008  0000000000000002   A       7     0     2
  [10] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          00000000004003a0  000003a0
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       8     1     8
  [11] .rela.dyn         RELA             00000000004003c0  000003c0
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018   A       7     0     8
  [12] .rela.plt         RELA             00000000004003d8  000003d8
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   A       7    14     8
  [13] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000400408  00000408
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [14] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000400420  00000420
       0000000000000030  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [15] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000400450  00000450
       00000000000001e8  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [16] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000400638  00000638
       0000000000000016  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [17] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000400650  00000650
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000400660  00000660
       0000000000000034  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [19] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000400698  00000698
       00000000000000dc  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [20] .ctors            PROGBITS         0000000000600e30  00000e30
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .dtors            PROGBITS         0000000000600e40  00000e40
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .jcr              PROGBITS         0000000000600e50  00000e50
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000600e58  00000e58
       00000000000001a0  0000000000000010  WA       8     0     8
  [24] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000600ff8  00000ff8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [25] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000601000  00001000
       0000000000000028  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [26] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000601028  00001028
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [27] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000601038  00001038
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [28] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001038
       0000000000000039  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [29] .comment.SUSE.OPT PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001071
       0000000000000006  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [30] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001080
       0000000000000060  0000000000000000           0     0     16
  [31] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000010e0
       000000000000005f  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000113f
       0000000000000232  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [33] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001371
       0000000000000133  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [34] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000014a4
       000000000000011e  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [35] .debug_frame      PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000015c8
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000           0     0     8
  [36] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001620
       0000000000000115  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [37] .debug_loc        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001735
       00000000000000fe  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [38] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001833
       0000000000000050  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [39] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001883
       0000000000000192  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [40] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00002498
       00000000000007c8  0000000000000018          41    65     8
  [41] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00002c60
       0000000000000244  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000774 0x0000000000000774  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e30 0x0000000000600e30 0x0000000000600e30
                 0x0000000000000208 0x0000000000000218  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e58 0x0000000000600e58 0x0000000000600e58
                 0x00000000000001a0 0x00000000000001a0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x000000000000005c 0x000000000000005c  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000660 0x0000000000400660 0x0000000000400660
                 0x0000000000000034 0x0000000000000034  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e30 0x0000000000600e30 0x0000000000600e30
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.SuSE .note.gnu.build-id .hash .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.SuSE .note.gnu.build-id
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
   08     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got

Dynamic section at offset 0xe58 contains 21 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x400408
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x400638
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x4002b0
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x4002d8
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x400358
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x4002f8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              61 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x601000
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           48 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x4003d8
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x4003c0
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x4003a0
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x400396
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x3c0 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000600ff8  000300000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x3d8 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000601018  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 puts + 0
000000601020  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main + 0

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type Advanced Micro Devices X86-64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
   3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 83 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000400238     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000400254     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000400274     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 000000000040028c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 00000000004002b0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 00000000004002d8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 00000000004002f8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     8: 0000000000400358     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8
     9: 0000000000400396     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    10: 00000000004003a0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
    11: 00000000004003c0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
    12: 00000000004003d8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
    13: 0000000000400408     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13
    14: 0000000000400420     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14
    15: 0000000000400450     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15
    16: 0000000000400638     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16
    17: 0000000000400650     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17
    18: 0000000000400660     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18
    19: 0000000000400698     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19
    20: 0000000000600e30     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20
    21: 0000000000600e40     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21
    22: 0000000000600e50     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
    23: 0000000000600e58     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23
    24: 0000000000600ff8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24
    25: 0000000000601000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25
    26: 0000000000601028     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   26
    27: 0000000000601038     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   27
    28: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   28
    29: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   29
    30: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   30
    31: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   31
    32: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   32
    33: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   33
    34: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   34
    35: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   35
    36: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   36
    37: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   37
    38: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   38
    39: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS init.c
    40: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
    41: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS initfini.c
    42: 000000000040047c     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 call_gmon_start
    43: 0000000000400648     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 _real_fini
    44: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    45: 0000000000600e30     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 __CTOR_LIST__
    46: 0000000000600e40     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 __DTOR_LIST__
    47: 0000000000600e50     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 __JCR_LIST__
    48: 00000000004004a0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 __do_global_dtors_aux
    49: 0000000000601038     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   27 completed.6159
    50: 0000000000601040     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   27 dtor_idx.6161
    51: 0000000000400510     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 frame_dummy
    52: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    53: 0000000000600e38     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 __CTOR_END__
    54: 0000000000400770     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __FRAME_END__
    55: 0000000000600e50     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 __JCR_END__
    56: 0000000000400600     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 __do_global_ctors_aux
    57: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS initfini.c
    58: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS 24173361_generating-an-ob
    59: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS elf-init.c
    60: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
    61: 0000000000600e2c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 __init_array_end
    62: 0000000000600e58     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 _DYNAMIC
    63: 0000000000600e2c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 __init_array_start
    64: 0000000000601000     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    65: 0000000000400560     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __libc_csu_fini
    66: 0000000000601028     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT   26 data_start
    67: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
    68: 0000000000601038     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   26 _edata
    69: 0000000000400638    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _fini
    70: 0000000000600e48     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    21 __DTOR_END__
    71: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    72: 0000000000601028     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   26 __data_start
    73: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    74: 0000000000601030     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    26 __dso_handle
    75: 0000000000400650     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 _IO_stdin_used
    76: 0000000000400570   137 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __libc_csu_init
    77: 0000000000601048     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 _end
    78: 0000000000400450     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _start
    79: 0000000000601038     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 __bss_start
    80: 000000000040053c    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 main
    81: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
    82: 0000000000400408     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _init

Histogram for bucket list length (total of 3 buckets):
 Length  Number     % of total  Coverage
      0  1          ( 33.3%)
      1  1          ( 33.3%)     33.3%
      2  1          ( 33.3%)    100.0%

Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 4 entries:
 Addr: 0000000000400396  Offset: 0x000396  Link: 7 (.dynsym)
000:   0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.2.5)   2 (GLIBC_2.2.5)   0 (*local*)

Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entries:
 Addr: 0x00000000004003a0  Offset: 0x0003a0  Link: 8 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.2.5  Flags: none  Version: 2

Notes at offset 0x00000254 with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
  OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.4

Notes at offset 0x00000274 with length 0x00000018:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  SuSE                 0x00000004   Unknown note type: (0x45537553)

Notes at offset 0x0000028c with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
  Build ID: 710ef458701fed230f91233a227b7b10c024e2ed
```

While, that is a lot of detail for such a little file.  Here is how to break it down problematically.  First, the elf(64) header:

```
typedef struct elf64_hdr {
   unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];     /* ELF "magic number" */
   Elf64_Half e_type;
   Elf64_Half e_machine;
   Elf64_Word e_version;
   Elf64_Addr e_entry;           /* Entry point virtual address */
   Elf64_Off e_phoff;            /* Program header table file offset */
   Elf64_Off e_shoff;            /* Section header table file offset */
   Elf64_Word e_flags;
   Elf64_Half e_ehsize;
   Elf64_Half e_phentsize;
   Elf64_Half e_phnum;
   Elf64_Half e_shentsize;
   Elf64_Half e_shnum;
   Elf64_Half e_shstrndx;
   } Elf64_Ehdr;
```

The secret to creating an elf file is to understand the above structure. This is the first bit of the file your C program must write. Although too lengthy to detail here, you can find this structure in `elf.h`; which is located (on most Linux systems) here:  `/usr/include/elf.h`.

Comment: This is great so far! Please continue!

Comment: @user3689979, enough?